# Run Xswipe at startup

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I want to run [Xswipe](https://github.com/iberianpig/xSwipe) for my xps 13 (sputnik) build.

I have added it to `gnome-session-properties`.

The command is:

```
perl ~/xSwipe-master/xSwipe.pl
```

But it does not run at startup.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what you add to the gnome-session-properties is equivalent to a command run by using Alt+F2 and running a command. You can't run scripts that way as far as I've been aware.

I think the proper way to get a script to run on startup is to add that command in:

```
/etc/rc.local
```

Before exit 0. I haven't done it myself though. Take a look [here](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown).

Comment: I got it to work with gnome-session-properties; Using perl /home/username/xSwipe-master/xSwipe.pl   Thanks for the help!